# Copy microsoft project resource view to excel sheet - Using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am setting up a spreadsheet to copy resourcing sheet data from an Microsoft Project File.
I am going to plot resource usage sheet in excel
I need to copy each resource name and then copy they Date / day and corresponding Hours for each resource.

I am trying the follow code

```
'Set start export date
StartDate = FindStartDate

'Loop through each project and export resources
Dim sTask As Task ' The Summary Task
For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
     If Not t Is Nothing Then
        If t.ID > 1 Then 'skip heading
            If t.Summary Then 'this is a summary heading

                    If Not t.Status = pjComplete Then

                        'Set project description and project task object
                        Set sTask = ActiveProject.Tasks(t.ID)
                        key = Trim(t.Name & "--" & t.Text2)


                        Dim st As Task 'sub tasks
                        For Each st In t.OutlineChildren
                             If Not st.Summary Then
                                 Dim r As Resourcee
```

[image]

The goal is to output it in to a spreadsheet so it can be converted to a histogram.

And the Date range is daily 
[image]

Comment: Your question is about exporting the Resource Usage data but you are looping through *tasks* instead of looping through ***resources***. Why is that? Do you have any code that shows what you have done so far to export data to Excel? Can you provide a screenshot of what the data will look like in Excel?

Comment: Also, see if [Visual Reports](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/pick-the-right-report-in-project-61324235-aaec-4eef-acab-4c5245fedaeb) will meet your needs. See [answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ms-project-2016-resource-usage-export-to-excel/...](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ms-project-2016-resource-usage-export-to-excel/7e7e8335-928c-41c3-a4b3-fa03ec8a4bac?auth=1).

Comment: I have updated the question with the output to excel. Thanks all

Comment: Yes I started thinking I should look in the Standard Gant Chart view and loop through each task and get the corresponding resource assigned to it. But I thought a simpler approach would just be to copy the resource sheet view and load it into excel.

Comment: Copying the Resource Usage sheet (as it looks like you did in your screenshot) is a quick way to get that data to Excel. It sounds like you need something else or something more...